# Material UI: theme not applied to custom library components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, git, material-ui, styled-components

I'm using Material UI v5 with react/typescript/styled components. I have created a custom theme that works as expected. I have that theme, along with some components in a separate library, which I've put in the repo https://github.com/Findeton/mui-lib . I also have a storybook setup and I can see the theme working on mui-lib.

But then, I use the mui-lib in an app, in this case defined https://github.com/Findeton/mui-app . What I see is that the theme (which I import from mui-lib) is applied to components defined in the app, but not to components imported from mui-lib.

This a Codesandbox where you can try it https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/modest-water-j35rwd

Another way to reproduce it is to run:

```
git clone https://github.com/Findeton/mui-app.git
git submodule update --init
cd mui-lib && yarn && yarn build:dev && cd ..
yarn
yarn start
```

PD: Also I've noticed that the sources/sourcemaps from mui-lib are not available on the browser even when I'm using build:dev/ development mode on webpack.